# Java Classloader Dependency Issue

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I have a project called project1. This project1 depends on project2 and this dependency is marked to the test scope. Now project2 has a dependency on jar1. The jar1 has a dependency on another jar called someJar with a certain version.

At the same time project1 also has a direct dependency to someJar but with a different version. Now when I run my application's unit test in project1, the someJar in project1 kicks in and since it uses an older version, my unit test fails with a NoSuchMethodFound Exception. How can I control this so that when I run my unit tests in project1, jar1's someJar is loaded and not project1's someJar is loaded? Any clues?

Comment: Use dependencyManagement in pom

Comment: Make sure you always maintain only one version of that dependency jar. If you are using maven then add exclude tag in dependency tag of jar which is referring old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so called Jar Hell. I had faced this issue earlier and solved as well...I thought to help people facing this issue and hence wrote a small blog on my Blogger Please refer the same for more details

[My Blog on Jar hell](http://akshaybobde.blogspot.in/2014/07/resolving-jar-hell-hack.html)